# Add "x" Element To Active Menu Links

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and trying to work out how to add an 'x' (or other indicator) to an active menu item like here:

http://www.evoltaste.com/

When you select a menu item under "Work" the chosen link goes bold and adds an "x" prefix.  The bold bit I understand but how is the "x" added?  I've looked through the CSS stylesheets but can't isolate the class or whatever is controlling that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `::before` and `::after` *pseudo-elements* in **CSS**.

In this case, you could use something like:

```
.my-link::before {
  content: 'X';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.my-link::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-link:hover::before {
  content: 'X';
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="my-link">My Link - hover over me</a>
```